# Separating classes in header and source causes build errors

Tags: c++

The following code snippets are intentionally made simple only to illustrate the problem. There are two cases I want to show here. The first one in which all code is put in a single file as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
    double data;

public:
    Base(double data);
};

Base::Base(double data = 10) : data{data}{}


class Derived : public Base
{
};



int main()
{
    Derived d;
    std::cout<<"End of program";
    return 0;
}
```

So far so good. Everything works as expected.

However, if I split the classes into their headers and sources as follows.

**Base.hpp**

```
// Base.hpp
#pragma once
class Base
{
protected:
    double data;

public:
    Base(double data);
};
```

**Base.cpp**

```
// Base.cpp
#include "Base.hpp"

Base::Base(double data = 10) : data{data} {}
```

**Derived.hpp**

```
// Derived.hpp
#pragma once
#include "Base.hpp"

class Derived : public Base
{
};
```

**Derived.cpp**

```
// Derived.cpp
#include "Derived.hpp"
```

**separate.cpp**

```
// separate.cpp
#include "Derived.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Derived d;
    std::cout<<"End of program";
    return 0;
}
```

I got a lot of build errors as follows.

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file <

Starting build...
"C:\mingw32\bin\g++.exe" -g *.cpp -o separate.exe -I F:\StackExchange\Programming\VSCode-Template/cpp
separate.cpp: In function 'int main()':
separate.cpp:5:13: error: use of deleted function 'Derived::Derived()'
     Derived d;
             ^
In file included from separate.cpp:1:
Derived.hpp:4:7: note: 'Derived::Derived()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Derived : public Base
       ^~~~~~~
Derived.hpp:4:7: error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()'
In file included from Derived.hpp:2,
                 from separate.cpp:1:
Base.hpp:8:5: note: candidate: 'Base::Base(double)'
     Base(double data);
     ^~~~
Base.hpp:8:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Base.hpp:2:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)'
 class Base
       ^~~~
Base.hpp:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Base.hpp:2:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)'
Base.hpp:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
```

## Questions

Could you tell me why this issue happened and  how to fix it?

Comment: Honestly, it is not a typo but my misunderstanding about default parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default argument belongs in the declaration (in the header), not in the definition (in the .cpp file).

Answer (score 1):

> Could you tell me why this issue happened

It is because you removed the default argument from the declaration of the constructor. It is no longer a default constructor. The default argument in the definition is only visible in the translation unit containing the definition.

> how to fix it?

Move the default arguments of the constructor back to the declaration.